# index 0 beyond bounds for empty array For iOS 8 for Table view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8

I have created one tab;e programmatically code is below:

```
        tblWebserviceList=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(345, 304, 430, 180)];
        tblWebserviceList.delegate=self;
        tblWebserviceList.dataSource=self;
        tblWebserviceList.rowHeight=30;
        [WebServiceView addSubview:tblWebserviceList];
```

Now this table view is added on one view named `WebServiceView` which I add on one button click

The delegate method for table view are as below

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Method : numberOfRowsInSection
// method to set the number of row in the tableview
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
            if(arrWebServiceList==nil)
                return 0;

            return [arrWebServiceList count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
            {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
                cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            }
            cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
            cell.textLabel.text=[arrWebServiceList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            return cell;
}
```

On one button click I have code of adding the `WebServiceView` as below:

```
 tblWebserviceList.hidden=YES;
    [self.view addSubview:WebServiceView];
```

here before adding that parent view I m hiding the `tblWebserviceList` and will show whenever required,

This is all about the code.

Now my question is this code run fine on ios 7.0 and 7.1.

But app crashes on ios 8.0. To debug this code im using beta 6 of xcode 6.

The crash log is as

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x22c6bf77 0x30134c77 0x22b803d7 0x40b94f 0x26315501 0x263192db 0x2624434f 0x25c724c5 0x25c6dec1 0x25c6dd49 0x25c6d737 0x25c6d541 0x25c6744d 0x22c32835 0x22c2ff19 0x22c3031b 0x22b7dda1 0x22b7dbb3 0x2a063051 0x262a5c41 0x53aed 0x53438)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I think this issue only come when first time data source array of table contains the 0 record because at first I show the empty table and then add record after inserting the web service url.

If the records are greater than 0 then it will work fine. issue only for 0 records.

Pls help me!!!

Thanks

Comment: Stacktrace and relevant source file please.

Comment: sorry I have posted the code. I could not provide u file and other stuff

Comment: OK I doubt anyone can help then.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
cell.textLabel.text=[arrWebServiceList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

to

```
cell.textLabel.text = [arrWebServiceList count] > 0 ? [arrWebServiceList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] : @"DummyText";
```

Comment: For empty array, control not goes into the cellForRowAtIndePath functions. I already debugged this. For empty array I return number of rows =0

Comment: @svrushal, it's shouldn't, but who knows what does ios 8 beta

Comment: @Cy-4AH, but I want my app should run on ios 8. Thats why im checking it.

Comment: @ Cy-4AH No need to downvote if u are not able to ans the question:(

Comment: @svrushal, I am not downvoter. I think we just need wait for ios 8 release. I have also seen in ios 8 problem, when environment was throwing `unrecognized selector` exception for object that implements that selector, in ios 6 and 7 all was fine.